# How do I add a className on several elements and define them?

Tags: javascript

I have a task that is to download the document

element and to put the class with the class name "bodyCopy" for them, with tag selektor and class manipulation. The class is given in a seperate CSS document.

I did a code for this see below. And the code works, but when I validate the code it's undefined and the code below doesn't run because of this define-error. Is my code wrong even if it's working or did I miss to define something?

```
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
       for(i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
          a[i].classList.add("bodyCopy");   
       }
```

When i validate is says that a[i] is undefined, and the code below can't continue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `i <= a.length` should be `i < a.length`. The highest index is `a.length - 1`, not `a.length`. `a[a.length]` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   a[i].classList.add("bodyCopy");   
}
```

Simply needs to be `<` and not `<=`... it's just an off-by-one bug. It works because the error doesn't occur until it's already completed all it's tasks.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a great answer, but there's another option. You can also use `forEach` function, is a lot code cleaner and does the same.

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("p");
elements.forEach(p=>{
    p.classList.add("bodyCopy");
});
```

Comment: `getElementByTagName()` doesn't return an actual array, instead it's an `HTMLCollection`, which doesn't have `forEach()`, but you can do it like this: `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("p")).forEach(p => p.classList.add("bodyCopy"));`

Comment: You are right... I forgot to change `getElementsByTagName()` to `querySelectorAll`, which was my main idea...